# Get the N elements from array based on the position

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want a function that returns the sub array which takes a position & the no. of elements I want. I think there may be some algorithm to find the pivot point or something & from that I can get the sub array, but I totally forgot it.

```
Example: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
I want 6 elements
if position = 0, then I want [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
if position = 1, then [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
if position = 2, then [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
if position = 3, then [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
if position = 4, then [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
if position = 5, then [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
if position = 6, then [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
if position = 7, then [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
if position = 8, then [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
if position = 9, then [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
simply get the middle of N elements based on the position I pass.
```

I can write up my own `loop` which will contain multiple `if-else` conditions to get it done. But I feel there may be some easy way to do it.

I didnt include my incomplete code snippet because I strongly feel there must be some algorithm to do this.

Comment: How is the position used? Why do you skip the first element when you specify position to be 4?

Comment: It's like, if my position is center position of array get me middle array having N elements. does it makes sense

Comment: OK I missed that, I was getting a start index and minimum length. I'll update my snippet accordingly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is : `Array.prototype.slice(...)`

It's neatly documented here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
var n = 6;
var start = Math.max(0, Math.min(Math.floor(position-n/2), a.length-n));
return a.slice(start, start+n);
```

Comment: Updated according to your comment in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

function getSubArray(idx, _length, _array) {
  return _array.slice(idx, idx + _length);
}

var subArray = getSubArray(3, 6, a);
```

Comment: It works nice, but `getSubArray(5, 6, a) => [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] `, I expect `[4,5,6,7,8,9] or [3,4,5,6,7,8]` that looks middle from position 5.

Comment: Hey @LonelyPlanet, Our goal is to pass an initial starter position, isn't? And then, count the forward items. If you want return, `[4,5,6,7,8,9]`, you should call `getSubArray(3, 6, a)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an offset for the postion and get the the start value first for slicing.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    n = 6,
    i, 
    start;

for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    start = Math.max(Math.min(i - n / 2, a.length - n), 0);
    console.log(i, ': ', a.slice(start, start + n).join());      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only need is to check if you are not gonna check a pos that doesn't exist. Like :

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var n = 6; // Number of result you want
var x = 8; // Pos you want

// If you gonna exceed your length, we got only the n last element
if((x+(n/2)) > a.length) { 
    console.log(a.slice(a.length-n)); 
// Otherwise, if under 0, we got the n first
} else 
    if((x-(n/2)) < 0) { console.log(a.slice(0,n) ); 
// Default case
    } else { 
console.log(a.slice((x-(n/2)),(x+(n/2))));
}
```

This is not the smartest way, but he can give you some hint. I used the slice as other mentionned to avoid a lot of if, but you should do **GENERIC** test.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
n = 6;
function split(position) {
    var start = Math.min(Math.max(position - Math.floor(n/2), 0), a.length - n);
    var stop = Math.min(start+n, a.length);
    return a.slice(start, stop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the Math object at all. You may simply do as follows;

```js
function getArr(a,n,d){
  n = n - 4 < 0 ? 0
                : a.length - d > n - 4  ? n - 3
                                        : a.length - d;
  return a.slice(n,n + d);
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
   diff = 6;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) console.log(JSON.stringify(getArr(arr,i,diff)));
```

Answer (score -2):

no need of if-else you can use arr[position] to arr[8]. have you got

```
function getArr(arr,position,requiredNumbers){
return arr.slice(position, position+requiredNumbers);
}
```